# Why queues and stacks are declared as pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, stack, queue

I'm studying Data Structures, and I'm not getting why stacks and queues need to be declared like:

```
struct stack *Stack;
```

(forget about the `struct` syntax)

I mean, why it is always declared as a pointer?

Comment: This question is not limited to stacks and queues. This is a question involving arrays and linked lists and every type of data structures. You should try to find out why pointers, in general, are useful.

Comment: coz, you don't know the actual size of the running stack/queue. Pointers come handy in such situations.

Comment: So... see if I got it or no...I should use pointers because I'm going to use malloc() and it returns an adress of the memory?

Comment: So your question isn't really why you always have to use pointers to structs (you don't), but why you ever use pointers in the first place?

Comment: I know when to use pointers. I just needed to understand malloc().

Comment: So ... what's the question? I'm really not sure now

Answer (score 4):

They are not always declared like that!

In general, declaring a variable as a pointer is useful for later allocating it dynamically. This can be due to a couple of reasons:

- The variable is too big for the program stack
- You want to return that variable from a function

In your case, let's think of two different implementations of stack:

```
struct stack
{
    void *stuff[10000];
    int size;
};
```

This is a terrible implementation, but assuming you have one like this, then you'd most probably not want to put it on the program stack.

Alternatively, if you have:

```
struct stack
{
    void **stuff;
    int size;
    int mem_size;
};
```

You dynamically change the size of `stuff` anyway, so there is absolutely no harm in declaring a variable of type `struct stack` on the program stack, i.e. like this:

```
struct stack stack;
```

Unless, you'd want to return it from a function. For example:

```
struct stack *make_stack(int initial_size)
{
    struct stack *s;

    s = malloc(sizeof(*s));
    if (s == NULL)
        goto exit_no_mem;

    if (initial_size == 0)
        initial_size = 1;
    s->stuff = malloc(initial_size * sizeof(*s->stuff));
    if (s->stuff == NULL)
        goto exit_no_stuff_mem;

    s->size = 0;
    s->mem_size = initial_size;

    return s;
exit_no_stuff_mem:
    free(s);
exit_no_mem:
    return NULL;
}
```

Personally, though, I would have declared the function like this:

```
int make_stack(struct stack *s, int initial_size);
```

and allocate the `struct stack` on the program stack.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your stack structure is defined (not just the layout of the `struct`, but the operations that manipulate it as well).

It's entirely possible to define a stack as a simple array and index, such as

```
struct stack_ {
  T data[N]; // for some type T and size N
  size_t stackptr; // Nobody caught that error, so it never existed, right? ;-)
} stack;

stack.stackptr = N; // stack grows towards 0

// push operation
if (stack.stackptr)
  stack.data[--stack.stackptr] = some_data();
else
  // overflow

// pop operation
if (stack.stackptr < N)
  x = stack.data[stack.stackptr++];
else
  // underflow
```

However, fixed-sized arrays are limiting.  One easy method of implementing a stack is to use a list structure:

```
struct stack_elem {
  T data;
  struct stack_elem *next;
};
```

The idea is that the head of the list is the top of the stack.  Pushing an item onto the stack adds an element at the head of the list; popping an item removes that element from the head of the list:

```
int push(struct stack_elem **stack, T data)
{
  struct stack_elem *s = malloc(sizeof *s);
  if (s)
  {
    s->data = data;   // new element gets data
    s->next = *stack; // set new element to point to current stack head
    *stack = s;       // new element becomes new stack head
  }
  return s != NULL;
}

int pop(struct stack_elem **stack, T *data)
{
  int stackempty = (*stack == NULL);

  if (!stackempty)
  {
    struct stack_elem *s = *stack; // retrieve the current stack head
    *stack = (*stack)->next;       // set stack head to point to next element
    *data = s->data;               // get the data
    free(s);                       // deallocate the element
  }

  return r;
}

int main(void)
{
  struct stack_elem *mystack = NULL; // stack is initially empty
  T value;
  ...
  if (!push(&mystack, some_data()))
    // handle overflow
  ...
  if (!pop(&mystack, &value))
    // handle underflow
  ...
}
```

Since `push` and `pop` need to be able to write new pointer values to `mystack`, we need to pass a pointer to it, hence the double indirection for `stack` in `push` and `pop`.

Comment: While `queue`s are often implemented with lists, I wouldn't advise using lists for stacks. A dynamic array as a stack has greater locality (and therefore fewer cache misses) as well as much fewer `malloc` calls. It's maximum memory usage also can be smaller by up to half as much.

Comment: @Shabbaz: that is all true; I was just going for something that was relatively straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

No, they don't have to be declared as pointers.

One can as well allocate stacks and queues as global variables:

```
struct myHash { int key; int next_idx; int data[4]; } mainTable[65536];
struct myHash duplicates[65536*10];
int stack[16384];
```

myHash also includes a linked list for duplicate entries using indices.

But as stated in the comments, if one has to add more elements to the structures, that was initially planned, then pointers come handy.

An additional reason to declare structures as pointers is that it typically with pointers one can access both the complete structure as a whole, any individual element of the structure or some subset of the elements. That makes the syntax more versatile. Also when the structure is passed as a parameter to some external function, a pointer is inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no need to implement stacks and queues with pointers - others have already stated this fact clearly.  Look at @JohnBode 's answer for how a stack can be perfectly implemented using arrays. The thing is that modelling certain data structures (such as stacks, queues and linked lists) using pointers, allows you to program them in a very efficient way in terms of both execution speed and memory consumption.

Usually an underlying array for holding a data structure is very good implementation choice if your use-cases require frequent random access to an element in the structure, given it's positional index (this is FAST with an array).   However growing the structure past its initial capacity can be expensive AND you waste memory with the unused elements in the array. Insertion and deletion operations can also be very expensive since you may need to rearrange elements to either compact the structure or make space for the new elements.

Since a queue and a stack don't have this random-acess requirement and you don't insert or delete elements in the middle of them, it is a better implementation choice to dynamically allocate each individual element "on the fly", requesting memory when a new element is required (this is what malloc does), and freeing it as an element is deleted.  This is fast and will consume no more memory than it is actually needed by your data structure.

Comment: If you implement a stack with a dynamically resizable array, you will use somewhere between equal to half as much memory as you use if you implement it with a linked list. Not to mention that for every push/pop you need a malloc/free. So a stack implemented with linked list is inferior to dynamically resizable array both in time and space efficiency.

Comment: @Shahbaz, I think you are absolutely right if we talk about queues holding native data types or small data structures. In this case, the accumulated size of the pointers linking nodes could far exceed the size of the unused dynamic-array cells, but as the size of the contained structure grows, this will not hold. Imagine a stack of 1KB sized structs; with just 8 free cells in your dynamic array, you'll be wasting 8KB of memory.  This slack space can be fought by keeping your dynamic array tight, but then you'll have a significant overhead moving such big elements around during reallocations.

Comment: @Shahbaz. I think our arguments really show that there's never a universal "best choice" for a data structure.  It will always depend on the problem we'll be attacking, don't you think? ;)

Comment: of course, there's never a universal "best choice". Nevertheless, most of the times you would implement the queue or stack with a "void *" parameter to prevent reimplementing for every data type you have. If you do instantiate the data directly in the elements, then yes, your logic is right.

Answer (score 0):

As aleady pointed out it depends on how big the struct is.

Another reason is encapsulation. The stack implementation might not expose the definition of struct stack in its header file. This hides the implementation detail from the user, with the downside that free store allocation is required.